Как реализовать воспроизведение аудио в PyQt5 с низкоуровневыми функциями?
Я хотел сделать воспроизведение звука в PyQt5 при нажатии на кнопку, но получалась задержка. Я использовал этот код:
self.player = QMediaPlayer()
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile('minecraft_click.mp3')
media = QMediaContent(url)  # Преобразуем QUrl в QMediaContent
self.player.setMedia(media)
self.player.setNotifyInterval(100)
self.player.setVolume(100)

Нужно чтобы задержки не было и звук воспроизводился автоматически. Вот реализация проекта:
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
    
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)


    def onClicked(self):
    # тут должен воспроизвестись звук без задержки
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

ИЗМЕНЕНО.
Файл Main.py:
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile('minecraft_click.mp3')
        media = QMediaContent(url)  # Преобразуем QUrl в QMediaContent
        self.player.setMedia(media)
        self.player.setNotifyInterval(100)
        self.player.setVolume(100)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.player.play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Файл MainWindow.py:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(363, 365)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(680, 528))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setKerning(True)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QWidget {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(0, 170, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: rgba(76,27,220,0.693);\n"
"    border: 3px solid rgb(82, 36, 181);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"background-color: rgba(76,27,220,0.603);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 0, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 170, 161, 41))
        self.button.setObjectName("button")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Launcher"))
        self.button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Звук"))


Assembler, 1. Что не так с ответом на ваш предыдущий ответ, почему вы не отвечаете? 2. Ваш код, текущего вопроса, должен быть воспроизводимым, опубликуйте модуль MainWindow.py и вставьте первую часть опубликованного кода в основной код, и лучше расскажите какая задержка у вас получалась и что собственно вы хотите сделать,  что значит: "... звук воспроизводился автоматически" ?

Под словом автоматически я подразумевал "сразу". А в модуле MainWindow.py находится скомпелированное окно

Assembler, я знаю, что находится в MainWindow.py. Что такое  "сразу", это до нажатия на кнопку или как? Еще раз, пожалуйста, прочитайте мой первый комментарий.

S. Nick, я внёс изменения в вопрос. Сразу это значит при нажатии на кнопку без задержки, а у меня задержка примерно 0,8 секунды.

Assembler, у меня ваш код работает нормально и я пауз не  наблюдаю. Попробуйте заменить url = QUrl.fromLocalFile('minecraft_click.mp3')
на
url = QUrl('minecraft_click.mp3')
и напишите как вы определяете паузу в  0.8 секунд.
